# Prevent starting with administrative rights

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

**Goal:**

It sounds a little bit odd, but I have to prevent that a software starts with administrative rights.

**Problem:**

I have a setup tool that installs the software very well. After completion the setup starts the software itself. Because the setup tool runs with administrative rights, the software that will be startet automatically after the setup does the same.

But all Settings that the program need, won't be written/read correctly that time, because due to the UAC virtualization, the config directory is different to the config directory the user would have without administrative rights.

**Question:**

Is there any way to downgrade from admnistrative rights to user rights, if the parent process owns administrative rights. App.config? StartParameter? or something else

Info: I'm using the INNOSETUP to build the setup tool.

Thx for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set [runasoriginaluser](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm#runasoriginaluser) flag for running application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can start a process non-elevated, however I'm not sure how this integrates with InnoSetup. The instructions are [How do I start a program as the desktop user from an elevated app](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2009/06/06/faq-how-do-i-start-a-program-as-the-desktop-user-from-an-elevated-app.aspx).

Consider marking your application with [appropriate manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx#S8) to suppress UAC virtualization, it will then use the same directories in both cases: non-elevated and elevated. And better use directories in user's profile without relying on virtualization.